# window.open(url) fails to download the pdf file

Tags: javascript

I am trying to open a URL, which points to a PDF, using window.open(url). In IE, the popup window flashes and nothing happens afterwords. When I access the same url directly using IE, PDF opens up perfectly.
In the HTML below, when I click on Link, I get the PDF but window.open fails. Moreover, if I provide a direct link of PDF in window.open that also works perfectly. Could any body shed some light on this?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE> New Document </TITLE>
</HEAD>

<BODY>
    <a href="http://phx.corporate-ir.net/External.File?item=UGFyZW50SUQ9NDk2Mjl8Q2hpbGRJRD0tMXxUeXBlPTM=&t=1">Link</a>
<script>
    url = "http://phx.corporate-ir.net/External.File?item=UGFyZW50SUQ9NDk2Mjl8Q2hpbGRJRD0tMXxUeXBlPTM=&t=1";        
    window.open(url);           
</script>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Most browsers block `window.open` when is called without user interaction in order to avoid popup advertisements.

Why are doing this anyway? Instead you should link directly to the PDF in the original document, where you can use `target="_blank"` if it must be in a new window. (Keep in mind, that there are users that don't like it if websites open new windows).

Comment: I don't have direct PDF link; when I access the URL, i mentioned in the code, it generates the PDF and return.

Comment: Then open this document in a new window and redirect to the PDF - preferably server side or if that is not possible - with `window.location.replace(url)`.

Answer (score 0):

This may just be my convention, but I always use `window.open()` like this:

```
var win = window.open(url);
```

Comment: Either way is valid. If you don't need access to the window you just created (as in the OP's case) there is no need to use the return value of the open method.